# Looking for scifi movie from the 90s/early 00s based on book

Tags: story-identification, movie, books

I am trying to remember a movie I saw a long time ago, which I think was based on a book but impossible to find the title again on google.

A few elements I remember:

- First I saw the movie on TV so it might have been straight to DVD, around 2005-ish
- The story starts with the main character has an accident/dies and wakes up in the water
- He reaches the shores and finds many other people just arrived as well
- It seems they reached like a vast empty alternate world, with no much human population so they wander around, kind of like prehistoric times
- They find some tribes of people who arrived previously in this alternate world and some of them are famous historical people, like Brutus or Caesar, but also more recent historical people
- It seems like everyone ends up in this world after they die, but not in a heaven kind of way, more like alternate earth where everyone arrives around the same time
- The main story I dont remember but towards the end there is a huge blackish tower with some strangely advanced people (compared to the whole movie) inside who seem to control this world...and the movie kind of ends there.

For some reason, I seem to remember the title includes the words Tower or World but this I am completely unsure and my mind could be tricking me.

Do any of these details remind anyone of a specific book or movie?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Cheers

Comment: Damn you're good, this is it hahaha!